# String checking in jstl error

Tags: jstl

I have to check a attribute from server , and depending upon the value, i have to set the color of the font. The code i used for the same is: I am very new in jstl. Can handle this with javascript or jQuery, but have a constraint , not to use js here. :(

```
 <c:if test="${error != null}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${error_code eq 'failed'}">
                    <p align="left"><font size="3" color="red">${error}</font></p>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test=test="${error_code eq 'success'}">
                    <p align="left"><font size="3" color="green">${error}</font></p>
                </c:when>
        </c:choose>
   </c:if>
```

And the server side code is:

```
if (result) {
    request.setAttribute("error_code","success");
    request.setAttribute("error","Object successfully created.");
} else {
    request.setAttribute("error_code","failed");
    request.setAttribute("error","Object creation failed.");
}
```

what i am doing wrong here:

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /tool/Content/content.jsp (li
    ne: 68, column: 18) **quote symbol expected**
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorH
    andler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.j
    ava:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.j
    ava:89)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now its working , I changed the code as:

```
<c:if test="${error != null}">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(error_code, 'failed')}">
                    <p align="left"><font size="3" color="red">${error}</font></p>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(error_code, 'success')}">
                    <p align="left"><font size="3" color="green">${error}</font></p>
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
        </c:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following line is incorrect. You have write "test" two times ;-)

```
<c:when test=test="${error_code eq 'success'}">
```